# Iron-router + Fast-render, why is this an endless loop?

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

why is this an endless loop? [ Iron Router + Fast Render + Blaze]

```
Router.route("/:cycle_uri", {
    name: "cycle"
    ,template: "home"
    ,onBeforeAction: function () {
        console.log("is there a loop here?") // this is what confirms that it's a continuous loop
        var cycle = Cycles.findOne({
            "uri": this.params.cycle_uri
        });
        if (typeof cycle === "undefined") {
            this.render("notFound"); return;
        } else {
            ActiveCycle.set(cycle); // if I remove this, there is no continuous loop anymore... but if I remove it I don't see how to have this info in the client
            this.render("home");
        }
    }
    ,waitOn: function () {
        Meteor.subscribe('featuredListsPub', {
            'program_id': this.params.cycle_uri
        });
    }
    ,fastRender: true
});
```

I was trying to update ActiveCycle variable so I can read it in the frontend but it's not actually working... I'm certainly doing something wrong, but would like to first understand why updating the reactive var is creating a loop.

I've also tried

```
if (ActiveCycle.get() !== cycle) {
    ActiveCycle.set(cycle);
}
```

but it also enters a loop... which I don't understand why

Comment: you need to return the subscription from waitOn function

Comment: i don't think you are supposed to render anything from within the `onBeforeAction` function. that belongs into the `action` itself.

Comment: You can call render in onBeforeAction no worries, it's fairly common practice for checking login status

Comment: @Guns, at the moment my code has evolved a bit and I need to subscribe to 2 publications, how could that work?

Comment: @w3jimmy, posted an answer for you... Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

for your question in the comments:

How do you subscribe to two publications:

here is my answer:

```
waitOn: function () {
   return [
      Meteor.subscribe('subscription1'), Meteor.subscribe('subscription2')
   ];
}
```

However, i strongly recommend:

- Create on publication and return two cursors
- Use Template level subscriptions

Good Luck!

An example of Template level subscriptions:

```
Template.templatename.onCreated(function () {
  Template.autorun(function () {
    var subscription = Meteor.subscribe('some_publication');
    if (subscription.ready()) {
      // do something
    }
  });
});
```

and within the template

```
<template name="templatename">
  {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
    <div>Your Template here...</div>
  {{else}}
      <p>Loading...</p>
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

A nice article is right [here](https://kadira.io/academy/meteor-routing-guide/content/subscriptions-and-data-management/with-blaze).

Comment: do you mean subscription template onCreated + router waitOn subscriptions, or just template onCreated subscription?

Comment: only template level subscription. Added an example in my answer

Comment: thanks, code is in a complete mess right now, but I'll be back asap